# Html forward slash not displaying properly (Chrome and Edge)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, microsoft-edge

Ok, so I have html code like the following:

```
<div class="aClass">Thing One/Thing Two/Thing Three</div>
```

and the "/" displays correctly on IE and FireFox, but for Chrome and Edge it doesn't. There is no specific CSS styling applied to the class or any explicit font-family. The image displayed is:

[image: The image displayed instead of "/"]

Also, specifc codes such as `&#47;` don't fix the problem

EDIT: I forgot to mention that I'm using bootstrap... Don't know if that has any impact or not.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the issue. I assume it's a font related issue. try specifying font family in you css.

Comment: That seems very weird. Could you reproduce it at jsfiddle.net or codepen.io?

Comment: From the image, I think @MaherFattouh is correct. It might be a font related issue.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tz89L2e8/1/

Comment: posted wrong fiddle at first, try opening it now.

Comment: I've tried using various font-families in the css. Even inline styling doesn't work right `<div class="aDiv" style ="font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif">` ... Not quite sure what's going on with it. And I can't reproduce it in jsfiddle.net or codepen.io - even a direct copy&paste of all the html/css/javascript doesn't reproduce what I'm actually seeing in my environment. I'm just stumped as to what's causing it. @MaherFattouh - I tried the font-family you used as well to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. The site that I'm working with, they have an extra css file that contains the font info.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Campton Bold';
  src: url('../fonts/campton/Campton-BoldDEMO.otf');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Campton Light';
  src: url('../fonts/campton/Campton-LightDEMO.otf');
}
html {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
body {
    font-size: 16px;
}
h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, .bold-text {
    font-family: "Campton Bold", sans-serif;
}
h1, .light-text {
    font-family: "Campton Light";
}
header p {
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

The "Campton" variations are what's causing the problem. I just have to change those and it's fixed.

Answer (score 0):

well if i'm understanding the same what you meant by the question then i've just tested it on mentioned browsers and it works perfectly fine. i don't see any problem. or if you can elaborate your question with the help of screenshots, it might help us to answer you properly..

following snippet might prove helpful.

```css
div.withCss{
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 20px;
  }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="aClass">Thing One / Thing Two / Thing Three</div>
  <div class="para"><p>Thing One / Thing Two / Thing Three</p></div>
  <div class="withCss"> Thing One / Thing Two / Thing Three </div>
</body>
</html>
```